# Golang Bun ORM many-to-many with attributes

Tags: go

According to the Go Bun [documentation](https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/relations.html#many-to-many-relation), for many-to-many relationships I would use the following code:

```golang
func init() {
    // Register many to many model so bun can better recognize m2m relation.
    // This should be done before you use the model for the first time.
    db.RegisterModel((*OrderToItem)(nil))
}

type Order struct {
    ID    int64  `bun:",pk"`
    // Order and Item in join:Order=Item are fields in OrderToItem model
    Items []Item `bun:"m2m:order_to_items,join:Order=Item"`
}

type Item struct {
    ID int64 `bun:",pk"`
}

type OrderToItem struct {
    OrderID int64  `bun:",pk"`
    Order   *Order `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:order_id=id"`
    ItemID  int64  `bun:",pk"`
    Item    *Item  `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:item_id=id"`
}
```

But how would I proceed, if the `OrderToItem` struct/table should store additional information for the relation, for example a creation date?

```golang
type OrderToItem struct {
    OrderID      int64      `bun:",pk"`
    Order        *Order     `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:order_id=id"`
    ItemID       int64      `bun:",pk"`
    Item         *Item      `bun:"rel:belongs-to,join:item_id=id"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time  
}
```

How would I access the `CreatedAt` variable of the `OrderToItem` struct?

Comment: If you need to access those, you can have  1 Order -> * OrderToItem relation and 1 Item -> * OrderItem relation. So instead of having 1 many to many relation, you will have 2 one to many relations

Comment: That sounds reasonable. Do you have a minimal code example, how an join of those two new tables in Go would look like? I would assume (starting at `Order`) I would add a relation to `OrderToItem`, but how would I then access the according `Items` from there?

Comment: something like this :`OrderItems []OrderToItem `bun:"has-many,join:id=order_id"``